# How can I disable spacebar intellisense commit in Visual Studio 2018 or 2019?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

How to disable commit intellisense by spacebar?

I found option to select commit charactors, but not spacebar.

I prefer to use `#define fi first` for competitive programming, but spacebar auto commit makes fi to first!

Please help me

Comment: are you talking about auto completetion while typing?

Comment: yes! I type fi and spacebar, it changes to first

Comment: why would you disable it just to write a macro that you wouldnt need if you kept it enabled? Simply dont use the macro, two problems solved at the same time

Comment: but sometimes I need to know if there is corresponding function or variable.

Comment: by "competitive programming" do you mean code golf?

Comment: I don't know code golf. 

but I mean codeforces or ACM-ICPC style programming challenges.

Comment: Yea gods and little fishes!  This is why I hate "competitive programming".  (It's still a valid question though.)